# Custom Cordova iOS plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I'm new in developing with cordova and would like to add a custom written iOS plugin from file system. I use cordova version 4.3.0 with iOS version 3.8.0.

When trying to add the plugin with `" $ cordova plugin add ../my_plugin_dir"` I get the following error:

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'at.researchstudio.knowledgepulse.reminder':Error: Uh oh!
".../plugins/at.researchstudio.knowledgepulse.reminder/src/ios/Kpreminder.m" not found!
```

But the m-source file is in this folder!!! What am I doing wrong??
Plugin-Structure:

```
at.researchstudio.knowledgepulse.reminder/
  plugin.xml
  src/
    ios/
      Kpreminder.h
      Kpreminder.m
  www/
      reminder.js
```

The plugin.xml looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="at.researchstudio.knowledgepulse.reminder" version="0.0.1">
    <name>Kpreminder</name>
    <description>Reminder Functionalities for KP</description>
    <keywords>KnowledgePulse reminder</keywords>

    <js-module src="www/reminder.js" name="reminder">
        <clobbers target="reminder" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Kpreminder">
                <param name="ios-package" value="Kpreminder"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <header-file src="src/ios/Kpreminder.h" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/Kpreminder.m" />
    </platform>

   </plugin>
```

Comment: which cordova version you are using?

Comment: cordova version 4.3.0

Comment: try not using dots on the folder name.

Comment: Error returned is missing files in the given path...try once adding your plugin into plugins folder and use command cordova build ios.

Comment: no success when changing folder name  (without dots); 
no sucess when adding it to plugins folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you may put you plugin in 'plugins'folder,put into other folder
like $project_folder/myplugins/at.researchstudio.knowledgepulse.reminder
then install it